# Simple Pizza Ordering Application in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

I was inspired by a previous post here that also wrote a pizza ordering application. This is the attempt I have made using OOP in mind as I thought that would be just the way to go.

Here is Pizza.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pizza {

    private String size;
    private ArrayList<String> toppings;

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getToppings() {
        return toppings;
    }

    public void setToppings(ArrayList<String> toppings) {
        this.toppings = toppings;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.size + " pizza with " + this.getToppings();
    }
}
```

Here is PizzaOrder.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PizzaOrder {
    private double totalOrderCost;

    private final ArrayList<Pizza> pizzas;

    public PizzaOrder(ArrayList<Pizza> pizzas) {
        this.pizzas = pizzas;
    }

    public void calculateTotalOrderCost() {
        final double LARGE_COST = 9.99;
        final double MEDIUM_COST = 7.99;
        final double SMALL_COST = 5.99;
        final double COST_PER_TOPPING = 0.5;

        for (Pizza pizza : pizzas) {
            switch (pizza.getSize()) {
                case "Large":
                    totalOrderCost += LARGE_COST;
                    break;
                case "Medium":
                    totalOrderCost += MEDIUM_COST;
                    break;
                case "Small":
                    totalOrderCost += SMALL_COST;
                    break;
                default:
                    totalOrderCost += 0.0;
                    break;
            }

            int totalToppings = pizza.getToppings().size();
            totalOrderCost += totalToppings * COST_PER_TOPPING;
        }
    }

    public double getTotalOrderCost() {
        return totalOrderCost;
    }

    public void printOrderSummary() {
        for (Pizza pizza : pizzas) {
            System.out.println("Ordered a " + pizza.getSize() + " pizza with " +    pizza.getToppings());
        }
        System.out.println("TOTAL ORDER AMOUNT: " + getTotalOrderCost());
    }
}
```

Here is the driver of the application

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PizzaOrderDriver {

    public static void printWelcomeMessage() {
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pizza Order Program!");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        printWelcomeMessage();

        ArrayList<Pizza> pizzas = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Enter the total pizzas you would like to order: ");
        int totalPizzas = scanner.nextInt();

        // Reading input regarding pizza size and pizza toppings
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPizzas; ++i) {
            Pizza pizza = new Pizza();

            ArrayList<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();

            String pizzaSize;
            System.out.println("Enter the size of the pizza Large, Medium, Small: ");
            pizzaSize = scanner.next();
            pizza.setSize(pizzaSize);

            int totalToppings;
            System.out.println("Enter the total amount of toppings on the pizza: ");
            totalToppings = scanner.nextInt();

            for (int j = 0; j < totalToppings; ++j) {
                System.out.println("Enter the topping: ");
                String topping = scanner.next();
                toppings.add(topping);
            }

            pizza.setToppings(toppings);
            pizzas.add(pizza);
        }


        // Creating PizzaOrder object and relevant information with regards to order
        PizzaOrder order = new PizzaOrder(pizzas);
        order.calculateTotalOrderCost();
        order.printOrderSummary();


        // Cleanup
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Along with a general review, I would like some ideas on how to extend this even further. I know what I have right now is rather very simple.

Thank you for reviewing my code.

Answer (score 4):

```java
private String size;
```

Could be an `Enum` instead, or a class. Both could also hold their costs.

---

```java
private ArrayList<String> toppings;
```

You should use the most generic interface of your types when declaring them as possible, as this allows to swap out the implementations without having to change everything. In this case it would be `List`.

---

```java
public class Pizza {
    // ...
}
```

You're duplicating data, you don't need to keep track of the number of toppings, the list is already doing that for you. They can easily get out of sync and therefor cause trouble.

You have a problematic API here, by allowing to set a `List` directly:

1. It will be `null` if not set.
   2.`null` can be set.
2. The `List` can be changed outside of the control of the class.

What would be a more clean solution would be to keep the `List` of toppings internal, and only expose a method to add (and if needed to remove) toppings. That would greatly simplify your class.

```java
public class Pizza {
    private List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getCount() {
        return toppings.size();
    }
    
    public Pizza addTopping(String topping) {
        toppings.add(topping);
        
        return this;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return toppings.length() + " pizza with " + toppings;
    }
}
```

Note that `toppings.toString()`, as it will be called for `String` concatenation, will not output the toppings at all.

---

```java
totalOrderCost += totalToppings * COST_PER_TOPPING
```

Always remember that `+=` is not shorthand for `a = a + b` but for `a = (TYPE_A)(a + b)`. So it might silently truncate data.

---

You could rewrite the `PizzaOrder` according to the same changes as for `Pizza` to add `Pizza`s to the order, like this:

```java
PizzaOrder pizzaOrder = new PizzaOrder();
pizzaOrder.add(createPizzaWithToppings());
pizzaOrder.add(createPizzaWithToppings());
pizzaOrder.add(createPizzaWithToppings());

Systemm.out.println(pizza.getTotalOrderCost());
```

---

```java
            String pizzaSize;
            System.out.println("Enter the size of the pizza Large, Medium, Small: ");
            pizzaSize = scanner.next();
```

Just declare the variable on the same line as assigning it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice in this review! I will be sure to implement these changes. Do you have any suggestions on how to extend this further?

Comment: Well, user input should be put into its own class. There should be an interface for that, so that the order can come from anywhere, as long as the interface is implemented. None of these classes should be concerned with their representation, that should be its own class, too. Then stop using doubles. And finally, all the prices and sizes should come from a configuration source, instead of being hardcoded. You can blow this up to a whole framework about ordering pizzas.